# Yii2 save selected checkboxList items with active form and seach Model

Tags: yii2, checkboxlist

I want to implement a checkBoxList in my Seachmodel but didn't find a good solution. How can i do this? In My Model i have an Array for the Values:

Model:

```
const ART_BLACK = 10;
const ART_GREEN = 20;
const ART_ORANGE = 30;

public static function colorText() {
        return [
            self::ART_BLACK => 'Black',
            self::ART_GREEN => 'Green',
            self::ART_ORANGE => 'Orange',
        ];
    }
```

Serach view (_search)

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'color[]')->checkboxList(Color::colorText()); ?>
```

After executing the search, all Elements are no longer selected. I can also put the array with the values in the SearchModel but still don't know what's best to save them to display again after the search.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just have to set the search model with separated available options and the selected option

```
class ColorSearchForm extends Model
{
    const ART_BLACK = 10;
    const ART_GREEN = 20;
    const ART_ORANGE = 30;

    public $available_colors = [
        self::ART_BLACK => 'Black',
        self::ART_GREEN => 'Green',
        self::ART_ORANGE => 'Orange',
    ];

    public $selected_colors = [];

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['selected_colors', 'safe'],
        ];
    }
}
```

in your controller you just do the standard

```
public function actionSearch()
{
    $model = new ColorSearchForm();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
        // echo '<pre>';print_r($model); exit(); //uncomment to debug
        // do something to search
    }

    return $this->render('index', [
            'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

to display the checkbox in your view:

```
<div class="goods-form">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'selected_colors')->checkboxList($model->available_colors) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. i found a mistake i did. in the $from->field i used 'selected_colors[]' which didn't work. 'selected_colors' works.

Answer (score 1):

create a value array as

```
$array = [10,20,30];
$searchModel->color = $array;
```

in _search.php

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'color')->checkboxList(Color::colorText()); ?>
```